# Cartoon about a team of alien hunters from the US

Tags: story-identification, aliens, cartoon

The cartoon used to broadcast in the late 1990s till mid 2000s. The cartoon consisted of three main characters, two guys and a girl. If I'm not wrong they were a team from the USA that hunts down aliens. One of them was a black man with metal arms.

I remember that they wore blue uniforms and that the metal arms guy was the rough one on the team, but I have no more details. I live out of the United States. It is not Generator Rex. This cartoon was on the air around the same time as [COPs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COPS_(animated_TV_series)) and [Ultraforce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraforce#Animated_series).

Comment: Do you remember anything else about the cartoon, like when you saw it, which channel it was on, or anything else about the team, any other major characters, or specifics about the aliens they were hunting?  Any information you add can help someone identify it.

Comment: Ben 10 was two guys and a girl hunting aliens in the US and I think the one guy could have metal arms but he wasn't black I think he was like Hispanic.

Comment: If this was on Cartoon Network, I know this one...

Comment: agree this sounds like Ben 10 - there are multiple iterations of it as well so it is possible that some character designs may have changed and would account for the discrepancy

Comment: I checked it out though and Ben 10 started in like 2005 and has a new season coming this year so the timeline might not be quite right...

Comment: Just to be sure, you mean "black" as in the race, not a color, right? There's an awful lot of guys with metal arms and a black color palette.
Also, what country are you in?

Comment: @bikthor please tell more about the show, at least the channel aired on?

Comment: hi I remember they use a blue uniforme, I don't want to sound racist or anything by saying the black so this metal arms guy was the rough one on that team, I have no more details, I live out of the united states so anyone will not channel it was on.
 is not generator rex, this was on air by the same time as COPs and Ultraforce.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like Generator Rex.  Rex is infected with nanobots, and works with a MIB style organisation that hunts down nano-infected lifeforms.

On the other hand, that started in 2010.

Comment: It's gotta be Generator Rex. (if some other clues are not given)

Answer (score 3):

## *Roswell Conspiracies: Aliens, Myths and Legends*

This could be [*Roswell Conspiracies: Aliens, Myths and Legends*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roswell_Conspiracies:_Aliens,_Myths_and_Legends), a series of 40 half-hour episodes that originally ran in the 1999-2000 television season.  It follows the adventures of The Global Alliance (a paramilitary organization based in Roswell, New Mexico, USA) as they maintain order and secrecy concerning alien activities on Earth.

The series has a large cast.  The primary characters are Nick Logan (a white man) and Sh'lainn Blaze (a pale humanoid alien woman).  One of the most frequently-appearing supporting characters is Jefferson Trueblood, a Native American man:

[image: Jefferson, Nick, Sh'lainn]

*L-R: Jefferson Trueblood, Nick Logan, Sh'lainn Blaze.*

Jefferson is a skilled hand-to-hand combatant and an expert in the use of weapons.  His complexion is somewhat darker than that of the white characters, and he frequently wears metallic armor on his arms and legs.

Dorian Wyrick is another agent of the Alliance.  His role in the series is less prominent than Jefferson's.  Dorian is black, and he wears a full suit of armor:

[image]

*Front L-R: Dorian Wyric, Sh'lainn Blaze, Nick Logan; Rear: Ti-Yet (a Yeti).*

The Alliance is ethnically diverse, including also Middle Eastern (Nema Perrera) and Asian (Keung Ling) characters.

[image: More members of the Alliance]

*Rear L-R: Simon "Fitz" Fitzpatrick, Dorian Wyrick, Jefferson Trueblood.*
    *Front L-R: Sh'lainn Blaze, Nick Logan, Nema Perrera, Keung Ling.*

The show's theme and title sequence starts at 0:17 in this video:

Answer (score 0):

[Men in Black: The Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Men_in_Black:_The_Series)?

Men in Black: The Series, also known as MIB: The Series, MIB: The Animated Series, and Men in Black: The Animated Series, is an American animated television series that originally aired on The WB's Kids' WB programming block from October 11, 1997 to June 30, 2001.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Men_in_Black:_The_Series)

See if this rings a bell:

The other option is Secret Saturdays, but the timeline doesn't match. Also hunting monsters, uniforms are wrong color. Guy with metal hand is spot on, though.

Opening video:

Answer (score 0):

I have the vauguest feeling this *may be*  at least one episode of  **[B.A.D.: Bureau of Alien Detectors](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/WesternAnimation/BureauOfAlienDetectors)**. Take a look at it and see if it rings any bells.

### First Episode